# Extract 720px thumbnail from facebook video

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to extract the thumbnail image from a video to facebook.

I should do it via json, the fact is that I can not extract the image to 720px.

I did so, but I get nothing, no errors or anything.

```
<?php 
/* 
10152765849330530 
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152765849330530&set=vb.48166220529&type=2&theater 

*/ 
$id = "10152765849330530"; 
$xml = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id); 

$result = @json_decode($xml); 

//var_dump($result); 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
$result = $result->format->picture; 

echo $result; 
?>
```

Ideas?

The link is to be extracted:

[https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfp1/v/t15.0-10/10470126_10152765850455530_10152765849330530_61772_571_b.jpg?oh=ea81bafb0b88da98068fe8697b058bd0&oe=5493EF9F&**gda**=1422872671_cf3d63eef79db332df7a30c8041abdd9](https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfp1/v/t15.0-10/10470126_10152765850455530_10152765849330530_61772_571_b.jpg?oh=ea81bafb0b88da98068fe8697b058bd0&oe=5493EF9F&__gda__=1422872671_cf3d63eef79db332df7a30c8041abdd9)

Comment: `echo $xml;` try this, what's the output??

Comment: this:
http://pastebin.com/CwsUGriw

Comment: and try `print_r($result);` just after the json_decode. What's the output?

Comment: this: http://pastebin.com/QH8Vn2Uw

Comment: I dont know. But the video is public, and it is a very famous Italian show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried to play with your code, works now -

```
<?php 
/* 
10152765849330530 
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152765849330530&set=vb.48166220529&type=2&theater 
*/ 

$id = "10152765849330530"; 
$xml = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $id); 
$result = json_decode($xml); 
echo "<pre>";
echo $result->format[0]->picture; 
?>
```

To fetch the 720px sized picture -

```
<?php 
/* 
10152765849330530 
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152765849330530&set=vb.48166220529&type=2&theater 
*/ 

$id = "10152765849330530"; 
$xml = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $id); 
$result = json_decode($xml); 
echo "<pre>";
echo $result->format[3]->picture; 
?>
```

Comment: Get 130x130 image not 720px

Comment: You want to fetch 130px size or 720px size?

Comment: Solved:

echo $result->format[3]->picture;

EDIT:I see now your update, tnx :D